# Given multiple path templates, how can I merge them into a single complete one

Tags: python, merge

Not sure if the title is descriptive but here's my problem. Given paths with optional parameters for example:

```
/client/get
/admin/client/get
/admin/client/get/2
```

How could I generate a template that express every possible version of this url. For the example it would be something like:

```
/{admin}/client/get/{id}
```

My main issue being keeping the order of the path. While I am able to generate a path with all arguments, I can't seem to do it in the right order. Resulting in templates like:

```
/client/get/{id}/{admin}
```

I have all paths in a python list as strings with no particular order like so:

```
/client/get
/admin/client/get/<int:id>
/admin/client/get
```

Comment: `/client/get` and `/admin/client/get` are separate endpoints. It wouldn't make sense to combine them under the same path expression.

Comment: They aren't. The reason being admin would only allow a user to access a client other than his own, the responsability doesn't change (its still getting a client). The user's access is automatically handled before entering the endpoint. Though this wasn't the question.

Comment: That sounds like separate endpoint behavior to me.... `/admin` paths require different authz and allow different actions. I would pull the business logic out of your endpoints such that `/admin/client/get/123` and `/client/get/123` both make the same underlying call (`api.client.get(123)` or etc), but I think trying to combine these into a single handler is wrong.

Comment: I combine them into a single handler because they all call api.client.get(x) in the backend. The only difference is that the non-admin endpoint assume the client using the currently logged in user. This allow us to fuse what would normally be 2-3 endpoints that all contains the same logic (pull client, verify it exists, returns an error if not, return the client otherwise) into a single maintainable method.I do understand that I am giving up explicit behavior for maintanability however. If it is wrong or not, is a matter of opinion but I believe it is worth it since we have 10-11 of these.

Comment: As a side note, permissions are set by url and not by endpoint. This is mainly why I do it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most optimized way of doing this but I ended up associating weights on path sections. Starting with the shortest url, I detect new sections and removed sections that I then assume are arguments. On the shortest path I use increments of 10 to leave space which I assume is reasonable. The diff method simply returns the difference between 2 lists. I also use a third element in the tuple indicating if the argument is optional, allowing me to add a '?' in the template. The code isn't clean but it works rather well:

```
shortest_string = reduce(lambda a, b: a if len(a) <= len(b) else b, paths)
paths.remove(shortest_string)

shortest = [e for e in shortest_string.split('/') if len(e) > 0]
weighted = [((i + 1) * 10, v, False) for i, v in enumerate(shortest)]

for p in paths:
    psplit = [e for e in p.split('/') if len(e) > 0]
    new_elements = diff(psplit, shortest)
    removed_elements = diff(shortest, psplit)

    for w in weighted:
        if w[1] in removed_elements:
            w[2] = True
        if w[1] in psplit:
            i = psplit.index(w[1])
            psplit[i] = w
    for i, ps in enumerate(psplit):
        if i < len(psplit) - 2 and isinstance(psplit[i + 1], tuple) and not isinstance(ps, tuple):
            psplit[i] = (psplit[i + 1][0] - 1, ps, ps in new_elements)
            weighted.append(psplit[i])
        elif not isinstance(ps, tuple):
            psplit[i] = (psplit[i - 1][0] + 1, ps, ps in new_elements)
            weighted.append(psplit[i])

template = '/'.join(['{' + (e[1][1:-1].split(':')[1] if e[1].startswith('<') else e[1]) + ('?' if e[2] else '') + '}'
                 if e[2] or e[1].startswith('<') else e[1] for e in sorted(weighted, key=lambda x: x[0])[1:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the paths in a python list, you start by selecting the shortest path because the shortest path would be the one where all optional parameters are missing (in the example: "/client/get")

Then, you look through the list for optional parameter additions at the start or end of the url using some sort of pattern matching like RegExp

```
import re

# holds smallest possible url
shortest = '/client/get'

# holds the url template you want
template = '/client/get'

# iterates through URLs
for poss_url in url_list:

     # Checks beginning of URL
     match = re.search('w+' + shortest, poss_url)
     if match is not None:
          string = match.group()
          string = string[1:]
          string = string[:-len(shortest)]
          template = '/{' + string + '}' + template

     # Checks end of URL
     match = re.search(shortest + 'w+', poss_url)
     if match is not None:
          string = match.group()
          string = string[1:]
          string = string[:-len(shortest)]
          template = template + '{' + string + '}'
```

Comment: This would indeed work for params that are appended / prepended. What about a case where the shortest is /client/get and one param is in the middle of it like so: /client/<path:p>/get ?

Comment: You'd have to split the shortest string at all '/' points and add the 'w+' in between.

Comment: Another process you could try is using the shortest URL and the longest URL to find the optional arguments. The shortest would have no optional parameters and the longest would have all of them, no?